# Change Tab position in Viewpager when clicked in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have passed string from fragment to fragment (from list view to swipe views). But My problem is when I click on a item in the listview, it  replaced fragment and goes to the viewpager  from the first, not the same item of the tab.

Here String is passing, but viewpager tab is not changing.

Listview fragment where I clicked on item:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         ////
         String text=listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString(ID_EXTRA, text);
         // set Fragmentclass Arguments
         SwipeNav fragobj = new SwipeNav();
         fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

         FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragobj);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
         ft.commit();
     }
 });
```

On the viewpager Swipe view page:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null && !getArguments().isEmpty()) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myInt = bundle.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA);

        myPagerAdapter  = new 
MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    } else {
        myPagerAdapter = new 
MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
```

I am unable how I will set the code so that I will be able to get the proper position of the tab in the viewpager when I will click on a item in the listview. I am using Single fragment for multiple tabs for Viewpger Swipe views.